# How can I call to a button Event Listener. even is not clicked?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-emulator, event-listener

I have button event listener with some actions inside which work good. I want to execute that event listener even I don't press that button I mean like execute a normal method. Because I don't want to copy and paste the same code. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You could declare the EventListener as an explicit class (rather than an anonymous inner class, as you are probably doing). From there, you can call the code from any place where it is referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous classes you create have access to methods in the surrounding class. I'm assuming you have an Activity with some code like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // do stuff here
  }
});
```

Instead, add a method to your Activity, say `private void doButtonStuff()`. Then set up your `OnClickListner` so the `onClick` method looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  doButtonStuff();
}
```

Now you can call `doButtonStuff()` without having to trigger the listener.

Alternatively you could programatically click the button:

```
Button button = ...
button.performClick()
```

This fires the attached OnClickListener, and makes it look and sound like the button was clicked. I think extracting the code into a method sounds like a better solution for your situation though.

Comment: for performance is better create a method and call it but right now the performClick() is exactly what I need. Thanks @matt-giles

Answer (score 2):

Just call

```
View.performClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to this the best way would be to put all those actions that are placed inside the eventlistener together in a method and then call this method inside your eventlistener and outside whenever you want. This is the best way so you can use this actions wherever you want. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

in Java8 I found that the programmatically 'click' is:

```
buttonName.doClick();
```

and NOT

```
buttonName.performClick();
```